# Do clear ceiling fan blades cause strobing?

Tags: ceiling-fan, recessed-lighting

A regular ceiling fan with wooden blades will cause a light strobe effect when mounted where the blades rotate under recessed/canned lights.  I am wondering if I would have the same strobing problem if I got a ceiling fan with [clear, acrylic blades like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XC9C3V5).

Anyone have any experience with this?  I am thinking since the blades are clear they won't block the light when the circle under the canned light so maybe there is no strobing?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm guessing there would be "less" strobing, but not "none". It's difficult to tell how much "less" there would be, and whether it would still be irritating.

Answer (score 3):

"Clear" things do not pass 100% of light hitting them. A quick search indicates "up to 92%" for acrylic, generically (may be less depending on details of fan blades and how clean they are) - as such, you will still have at least some "strobing" effect if the light source is above the fan.